# How to increase the number of cells in an array with Dynamic Allocation?

Tags: c++, arrays

So I am trying to use Dynamic Allocation to increase the number of cells in my array.

The array is from type Location that i created that includes x and y coordination

the process goes that way:

1. I create a new HEAP location array of the same size + 1
2. I use a for-loop to copy all the previous locations to the new array
3. Deleting the previous pointer
4. Pointing the previous one to the new one

what am i doing wrong?

This is the code :

```
void ExtendLocArray(location** ilocPrevArray, int inNumberOfMovements)
{
    // Variable definition
    location* locNewPathArray = new location[inNumberOfMovements];
    int       nIndex;

    // Code section

    // Copies the previous locations
    for (nIndex = inNumberOfMovements - 2; nIndex >= 0; nIndex--)
    {
        locNewPathArray[nIndex] = (*ilocPrevArray)[nIndex];
    }

    delete[](*ilocPrevArray);

    (*ilocPrevArray) = locNewPathArray;
}
```

Comment: Why are you looping in reverse? Why are you starting at inNumberOfMovements - 2 and not inNumberOfMovements - 1?

Comment: When asking questions please state what happens when you run the code and how that differs from your expectation. Questions like "What is wrong with this code?" are not constructive.

Comment: If this doesn't give you an appreciation for `std::vector<location> v;`, where this would simply be: `v.resize(inNumberOfMovements);`, nothing will.

Comment: im looping in reverse for no reason, just practice. this is -2 since i want to copy all the previous location and keep the last one open for the new location. the expectation is that my new array will have all the previous locations and a new one with no value in it as the last cell in the array. and for the 1 2 question , its 1 . the 2 is "2.", its a list

Comment: @Kesem David  How are you going to fill the new added element or can it be uninitialized?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow in the next loops the new cells I am creating are going to get a location

Comment: You didn't mention in the question what your actual *problem* is with this code, but you said in a comment on an answer that it crashes on the `delete[]` line.  How was the original array (the one passed in `ilocPrevArray`) allocated?  You can only `delete` something that was allocated with `new`.

Comment: @Wyzard it was allocated as a "new location"

Comment: `new location`?  Or `new location[1]`?  You also can't `delete[]` something that wasn't allocated as an array.

Answer (score 0):

A correct function can look the following way (provided that you want to copy elements of the arrays in the reverse order)

```
void ExtendLocArray( location** ilocPrevArray, size_t inNumberOfMovements )
{
    // Variable definition
    location* locNewPathArray = new location[inNumberOfMovements];

    // Copies the previous locations
    for ( size_t i = inNumberOfMovements - 1; i != 0; i-- )
    {
        locNewPathArray[i-1] = ( *ilocPrevArray )[i-1];
    }

    delete [] *ilocPrevArray;

    *ilocPrevArray = locNewPathArray;
}
```

You could declare the function like

```
void ExtendLocArray( location * &ilocPrevArray, size_t inNumberOfMovements );
```

that is you could use reference to the pointer.

Here is a demonstrative program I used a typedef for name location that the program could compile.

```
#include <iostream>

// simplified definition of location
typedef int location;

void ExtendLocArray( location** ilocPrevArray, size_t inNumberOfMovements )
{
    // Variable definition
    location* locNewPathArray = new location[inNumberOfMovements];

    // Copies the previous locations
    for ( size_t i = inNumberOfMovements - 1; i != 0; i-- )
    {
        locNewPathArray[i-1] = ( *ilocPrevArray )[i-1];
    }

    delete [] *ilocPrevArray;

    *ilocPrevArray = locNewPathArray;
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    location *p = nullptr;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        ExtendLocArray( &p, i + 1 );
        p[i] = i;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) std::cout << p[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    delete [] p;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Take into account that instead of writing the loop yourself you could use standard algorithm `std::copy_backward` declared in header `<algorithm>`. For example

```
#include <algorithm>

//...
std::copy_backward( *ilocPrevArray, 
                    *ilocPrevArray + inNumberOfMovements - 1, 
                    locNewPathArray + inNumberOfMovements - 1 );
```

Comment: @Kesem David In fact the same but it is better.:) It is more clear

Comment: i see, and still how come it just doesn't work? while debugging, at the second time i get to this delete[] the program crashes.

Comment: @Kesem David  Maybe you forgot to initialize the pointer initially to NULL.

Comment: @Kesem David Initially pointer ilocPrevArray shall be initialized by NULL (or nullptr). See my updated post.